# local and regular integral closure

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, singularity

Let $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ be a local domain with integral closure $B$ which is a regular local domain with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{M}$. Assume in addition that 
$A/\mathfrak{m} = B/\mathfrak{M}$ and $B\mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{M}$.

Does it follow that $A$ is regular and therefore $A = B$? If not in general, what if $\dim(A) = 1$?
It is enough to proof $\mathfrak{M}^2 \cap A = \mathfrak{m}^2$, since then it is $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ a vector subspace of $\mathfrak{M}/\mathfrak{M}^2$ but I wasn't able to show this.

The background is whether one can see a singularity in the case of just one analytic branch in the extended Ideal.

many thanks in advance!

Comment: In a large class of interesting rings arising in geometry, the integral closure is a finite module. In such cases, by Nakayama's lemma, your two conditions above ensures $A=B$.

Comment: Thank you Mohan. $A + \mathfrak{m} B = B$. Then $A=B$. This is perfect. I didn't see it.